# C++ how do i convert string to char

Tags: c++

```
int main
{
  string data;
  data = "q";

  char myChoice;

  myChoice = data.c_str();
}
```

I tried using `c_str()`, but it doesn't work. How do I convert `string` to `char`?

**Or rather I would like to ask**

```
int main()
{
  char myInput;
  // How to check user input is either a , b or c for char.
  cout << "Your Input ";
  cin >> myInput;
}
```

For `string` I can use `getline(cin,mystringvariable)`, then I check my stringvariable with an if-else statement.

But what about char?

Comment: `char myChoice = data[0];`

Comment: A string generally consists of more than one character. What do you expect the conversion to give you? Just the first character of the string?

Comment: A string is an array of characters, you just need to get the first element of this array in that case.

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question (after edit): You can use the code as written. `cin >> myInput` works if `myInput` is of type `char`. And of course you can use `if (myInput == 'a')` and the like as well.

Comment: Post your real code, not pseudocode.

Answer (score 5):

You can think of a string as an array of `char`'s. You can use `operator[]` overload with `std::string` class to extract a single character from the string:

```
// string data;
char myChoice = data[0]; // first char in "data"
```

For the second part of your question, you can check `char` variables with `if...else` as you do for strings:

```
char myInput;
...
if (myInput == 'a')
{
   ...
}
else if (myInput == 'b')
{
   ...
}
...
```

or you can use a `switch` statement as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can't convert a string to a char you will have to convert it to char array. if you want to grab a single character from a string you can do it by putting index of the character like data[index] and assign it to character variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getchar() from stdio.h.

```
int main() {
  char c;
  c = getchar();
  return (0);
}
```